# matplotlib.pyplot doesn't show SOME of the plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

**Edit: mistake of my own was found...**

"I'm trying to plot multiple curves on a graph with python, and from previous experiences matplotlib.pyplot seemed to be the way to go, but I'm defeated...

At the end of my code, I plot the main curve with

```
plt.plot(c0, c1)    # with c0 and c1 being two lists
plt.show()
```

and this works fine, but when I add another curve like :

```
plt.plot(c0, c1)    # with c0 and c1 being two lists
plt.plot=(c0, g)     # with g being another list **// here the = is my mistake**
plt.show()
```

then only the first one shows up. I also tried removing the main curve, but then I don't even have the plot windows...

Anyone knows this issue?"

Comment: can you also add plots you get after doing these steps?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib lets you add different plots in a single figure by default.

Some of the things you can check:

1) if c1 and g lists are the same( and they are overlapping in the plot?)

2) if g is empty(but you not even getting a plotting window after removing plot with c1 is definitely strange)

```
# plot first graph with red and next with green
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['red', 'green'])

plt.plot(c0, c1)
plt.plot(c0, g)

# maybe add legends as well to see if both are plotted?
plt.legend(['y = c1', 'y = g'], loc='upper right')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly I found there was a mistake of my own in my code that I failed to see... I actually wrote "plt.plot=(c0, g)" ...